# Console throws "ERROR TypeError: this.cipherTextService.storeCipher is not a function"

Tags: angular, service, components

## Some Background

I am developing a cipher decoding application. I'm currently at the very beginning of the project and am relatively new to **Angular**. I simply wanted to check if I could create a `service` and inject it into a `component`, as well as call my `storeCipher(cipher)` method.

### The problem

When my `logCipherText(cipher)` method is called, the error message below is output in my console. *I am running the latest version of Chrome*

### Error Message

`ERROR TypeError: this.cipherTextService.storeCipher is not a function`

I haven't really tried too many different things, as I'm pretty sure my code is extremely close to Angular's own examples. I did however, log  the type of my injected instance of the service, which gave me:
`service type: [object Object]`
So it's definitely not undefined.

I also did the same for my cipher String in my service and it logged:
`Service cipher variable type: undefined`

## **cipher-text.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CipherTextService {
  cipher = '';

  // WHERE THE PROBLEM IS!!!
  storeCipher(cipher) {
    this.cipher = cipher;
  }

  getCipher() {
    return this.cipher;
  }

  clearCipher() {
    this.cipher = '';
  }
}
```

## **cipher-input.component.ts** *injects `CipherTextService`*

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CipherTextService } from "../cipher-text.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cipher-input',
  templateUrl: './cipher-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cipher-input.component.css']
})
export class CipherInputComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cipherTextService: CipherTextService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  // WHERE THE PROBLEM IS!!!
  logCipherText(cipher) {
    console.log("service type: " + this.cipherTextService);
    console.log("Service cipher variable type: " + this.cipherTextService.cipher);
    this.cipherTextService.storeCipher(cipher);
    console.log("stored cipher: " + this.cipherTextService.getCipher());
  }
}
```

## **cipher-input.component.html** *calls `logCipherText()`*

```html
<div class="cipher-box">
    <input class="cipher-input" #cipher 
           placeholder="cipher text here" 
           (keyup)="logCipherText(cipher.value)"/>
</div>
```

### **What I'd expect**

I would expect to get `String` for the type of `this.cipherTextService.cipher` and I would then expect my `storeCipher()` method to store the value from the input text box into `this.cipherTextService.cipher`. My last log should then print out 
`stored cipher: 'whatever is typed'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the function.

```
  public storeCipher(cipher: String) {
    this.cipher = cipher;
  }
```

Comment: I tried applying that solution however I'm still getting the same problem.